# Installing Patches on MS SQL Server Tips

Tags: sql-server, patching

What is preventing Agent Service from starting after:

1. Failing to install CU.
2. Running a successful repair after disabling HIPS.

Background:
Installing CU's for Microsoft SQL Server I found I have an issue with the security software on my system.

After disabling the offending security software preventing my installation of patches and the repair process afterwards, I now have an issue with restarting the agent service.

Error during repair states:

```
Microsoft SQL Server #### Setup
The Following error has occured:
The process cannot access the file 'C:\windows\system32\perf-MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER-sqlagtctr.dll'
because it is being used by another process.
Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel this action and continue setup.
```

I am thinking I do not need to repair the service just yet, but something will need to be fixed.

New thoughts?

Comment: I so want to ask the question, "How do I fix a failed installation of MS SQL CU Patches?" and answer with after looking at all the great guidance from Microsoft to

 1. Backup system
 2. Backup Databases
 3. Install during off hours

Then add to all the forums out there, disable the offending security software during patch installation.

Comment: What is the security software that prevents you from installing CUs? In what way does it prevent install? Are there errors logged when you start Agent? What makes you think the install is corrupt? Did the install fail with errors, or succeed?

Comment: I think it should include all security software in general.
Regarding the install, I am updating my question with some information, and I may have a solution.

Comment: So did not find a solution, but found another bread crumb trail.

Comment: I've not had an issue with antivirus/security software preventing a CU install in the last decade. Details on what the software is, and how it is preventing CU install are very relevant to your question. Please update your question with details on the nature of the CU install failure, including any errors during CU install, or messages from your security software.

Comment: I think the security software issue may be a pointer flag to the underlying issue. System permissions and SQL Server permissions changed. Maybe the HIPS portion of security was blocking certain processes during the install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing to troubleshoot I did a search for `sql repair perf-mssql13.mssqlserver-sqlagtctr.dll being used by another process` and found the following article: [Knowledgebase article: File in use by another process](https://help.act.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024249874-Error-Error-The-process-cannot-access-the-file-C-Windows-system32-perf-MSSQL10-50-ACT7-sqlagtctr-dll-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process-When-Install-Microsoft-SQL-Server-2008-R2)

The repair continued after I applied the same advice to the file in question.

When repair completed I was not able to start the agent service. I did a search for the following from the "Event Viewer": `failed to initialize sql agent log (reason access is denied)` and found the following article: [MSSQLTIPS: SQL Server Agent Service Won't Start Due to Access Denied](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6322/sql-server-agent-service-wont-start-due-to-access-denied/)

What I found out: when SQL is installed, it places a security lockdown on the log directory. It changes owners and restricts access to only the agent service account. The DBA that installed the system used default settings to install SQL Server, and then changed the service accounts to domain accounts. In this case, I found it curious the Engine Service account had access to the directory, but not the Agent Log files.

Solution: Check the permissions on the Log Directory and look for errors regarding the files.

1. Rename the file from the error during repair.
2. Added the Agent Service Account permission to the log in question and log directory.

Comment: I am not sure if HIPS is a part of the problem or not, as the HIPS log shows a blocked action during install. However, I had a permission issue on the directories, so I think if someone has a similar issue, they should consider identifying whether HIPS exceptions are necessary during Patching SQL.

Comment: HIPS is not the cause of the issue in this thread. The cause of the issue at hand was permissions.